# PHP session not maintained after web service request

Tags: javascript, php

I am having requirement in PHP ,

Suppose
a link will be clicked in JavaScript from www.xyz.com and http GET request is executed from php onto www.abc.com with session ID.

```
var sessionID =/SESS\w*ID=([^;]+)/i.test(document.cookie) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
var resource="www.abc.com/Landing.php?token="+sessionID;
window.open(resource, '_blank');
```

in the Landing.php of abc.com(Raising web service request back to xyz.com)

```
$arrPostData=array();

$arrPostData['token']=$_GET['token'];

$post_data=$arrPostData;

$url="www.xyz.com/validateRequest.php";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);
```

---

In validateRequest.php(Cross verifiying the session id is same as that of the session)

```
if($_SESSION==$_POST)
{
    //execute code 
}
print_r($_SESSION).
```

The session is lost.(The session is empty.)
Please help..